# Echo function in an onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, echo

I can't fiture out how to call an echo PHP function in an onclick event, is there something I didn't do right ?

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="return(confirm('Confirm
that you've chosen ' + "<?php echo $value['info']['title']; ?>"));">
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between client-side and server-side programming as well as the basics of a page request life cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct your code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="return(confirm('Confirm
that you've chosen ' + "<?php echo $value['info']['title']; ?>"));">
```

Is going to be rendered as

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="return(confirm('Confirm
that you've chosen ' + "Whatever title"));">
```

You have double quotes in double quotes so it messes with the element rendering and the onclick attribute, you also have a single quote in single quotes:

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="return(confirm('Confirm
that you\'ve chosen <?php echo $value['info']['title']; ?>'));">
```

### NOTE

This does not mean your php code is being executed from an onclick event, you are simply rendering some text in place where your javascript can use it.

So when the page is rendered in the browser your code actually looks like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="return(confirm('Confirm
that you\'ve chosen Some Title Text'));">
```

Answer (score 0):

You rather call a some function on click and write your code in that function.

```
   <head>
    <script>
          function display()
          {
             //your code for on click here
           }
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     //your code for form
     <input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="display()" />
   </body>
```